# How to use user input as parameter in SQL query in windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I want to attach a DataSet with parameterized query. Something like a user entering a value in a text box then hit submit button.

I have created a Text Field and a click button event something like :

```
 private void Btn_GetProjDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userEnteredProjId = tab3ProjIdInput.Text;
    }
```

but now don't know how to use this userEnteredProjId variable in my query?

I haven't tried the manually coding all the data-connections path. Instead added the GUI in VS2012 to add a data source. Then using this data source I have learned we can add datasets, and then use these DataSets to just drag and drop in our form. So I created a dataset and then dataset toolbox, I added my table and created a query but don't know how to use the userEnteredProjId in my query here.

[image]

Comment: Please show us what have you tried?

Comment: What [research](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+sql+parameter) have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never want to just insert a value from a user into an SQL query because that is a huge SQL injection risk. It is better to use parameters, and better still if you do some validation on the parameters before using them. Here is a basic example of using a command parameter.

```
using (cmd command = new SqlCommand())
{
    string sql = "Select * from table where projid=@UserEnteredProjid";
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserEnteredProjid", your_value_here);      
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
    //do something;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you have a look at my updated image? Can I somehow use your suggested @UserEnteredProjId method there?

Comment: @camelbrush My answer won't help with what you are doing. Try looking at this MSDN page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try implementing this, and will come mark your post as an ans with what I did.
:)

Answer (score -2):

Well, your query is just a string variable I'm guessing, like "select * from table". You just want to take some user entered data to augment your query:

string query = "select * from table where projid = " + UserEnteredProjid;

Comment: Yeah, I've come to agree with the critics of this answer -- can't allow these vulnerabilities to exist in any code, no matter the context.